# Understanding Kotlin's yield function

Tags: kotlin, yield, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

I don't see a very clear definition of the [`yield`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence-scope/yield.html) function in Kotlin.

Example in the link above doesn't mention much but the following,

```
val sequence = sequence {
    val start = 0
    // yielding a single value
    yield(start)
    // yielding an iterable
    yieldAll(1..5 step 2)
    // yielding an infinite sequence
    yieldAll(generateSequence(8) { it * 3 })
}

println(sequence.take(7).toList()) // [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 24, 72]
```

But the above example doesn't point out the significance of yield.

- What does it mean that it is a suspending function?
- In what scenarios can it be advantageous?

Answer (score 48):

You can think of `yield()` as "**return, and next time start from where you stopped**":

```
val sequence = sequence {
    val start = 0
    yield(start) // first return
    yieldAll(1..5 step 2) // if called again, will start from here
    yieldAll(generateSequence(8) { it * 3 }) // if called more that six times, start from here
}
```

It creates state machine and stuff, but you can translate it to something like following in Java:

```
class Seq {
    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int state = 0;
    
    public int nextValue() {
        if (count.get() == 0) {
           return state;
        }
        else if (count.get() >= 1 && count.get() <= 5) {
           state += 2;
           return state;
        }
        else {
           state *= 3;
           return state;
        }
    }
}
```

In Java class we maintain explicit state by having two variables: `count` and `state`. Combination of `sequence` and `yield` allow this state to be maintained implicitly.

Note that `yield()` is a suspending function, so it may be invoked only from another `suspend` function or from within a coroutine.

Comment: So is it to do with coroutines or not?

Comment: I think you should increment your count for each call.

Answer (score 7):

Let's consider an example, where you are able to generate the next element of the sequence, but you do not see an easy way to implement a Java iterator.

```
fun fibonacci() = sequence {
  var a_0 = 1
  var a_1 = 1

  // this sequence is infinite
  while(true) {
    val a_n = a_0 + a_1
    a_0 = a_1
    a_1 = a_n

    //this is a suspend function call
    yield(a_0)
  }
}
```

The example uses the `yield` function to return the next element of the sequence. The function is an example of a `suspend` function in Kotlin. The call to the function suspends the execution of the `sequence{..}` block, so the call stack is free.

Let's say we do the following

```
fibonacci().take(10).forEach{ 
   println(it) 
}
```

Every iteration of the `forEach` loop will resume the `sequence{..}` block from the previous `yield` function call and let it run to the next `yield` function call. The execution flow will mix the `forEach` loop iterations with the `sequence{..}` block evaluation. You may try writing the same as Java `Iterator` to feel what Kotlin compiler does behind the scenes.

`suspend` functions in Kotlin are done minimalistic on the language and the standard library side, the rest can be implemented in libraries. I recommend checking the `kotlinx.coroutines` library for more insides, examples, and documentation
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: Would it be correct to say its no different then calling the method again? i.e. foreach(....) { fibonacci(10) } in Java?

Comment: Yes, the `.forEach{..}` is inline function, at the Java bytecode level it will be similar to Java's foreach